# How do I format a PHP array for use with AngularJS' ng-repeat directive?

Tags: php, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table that I want to populate using `ng-repeat`. I'm having trouble figuring out how to format my array so that it works. Here is what I have so far:

PHP (customers.php):

```
$customer_array = array();

$customer1 = array(
  'customer_id' => '1',
  'name' => 'John Doe',
  'city' => 'New York'
);
$customer_array[] = $customer1;

$customer2 = array(
  'customer_id' => '2',
  'name' => 'Jane Doe',
  'city' => 'Boston'
);
$customer_array[] = $customer2;

echo($customer_array);
```

AngularJS Controller (CustomersCtrl.js):

```
$http({
    url: 'customers.php',
    method: "POST"
})
.success(function (data, status) {
    $scope.customers = data;
})
.error(function (data, status) {
    $scope.status = status;
});
```

HTML:

```
<table>
<tbody ng-controller="CustomersCtrl">
    <tr ng-repeat="customer in customers">
        <td>{{customer.customer_id}}</td>
        <td>{{customer.name}}</td>
        <td>{{customer.city}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:
I'm wondering if this is because I'm loading the HTML code from above using the code below:

```
$routeProvider.when('/customers.php', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/customers.html',
    controller: 'CustomersCtrl'
});
```

Is it because the newly loaded html template is not bound to the controller before it tries to do the `ng-repeat` loop?

Answer (score 0):

You need to JSON encode the array before sending your response.

```
echo json_encode($customer_array);
```

That will give your javascript code something to work with.  Right now the only thing getting passed back to your javascript is the word 'Array' which won't do anything.

Comment: I added json_encode but it still doesn't work. I've used this feature a lot with ``ul li``, so I'm not sure why this isn't working.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if angular is worth it. This seems like such a simple thing to do, yet I've spent all day on it with no luck! Beyond frustrating.

Comment: What does the JavaScript console in your browser say? What do you get if you do a `console.log($scope.customers)` inside your `success` function? What does the network tab in the Google Chrome inspector (or similar tool) say is being returned from the server? Is your success function even being called? We can attempt to help you with specific problems, but "still doesn't work" isn't enough to go on when we can't see the actual error on your screen.

Comment: This is an old question and Angular has advanced quite a bit since then. But one thing I've come to understand about Angular is: If it seems very hard or clumsy to do something, you are probably trying to do it the wrong way in terms of Angular's intended use. Perhaps doing it in a different way makes it very logical and easy.

Answer (score 0):

If any body is having similar problems check if you have BOM marks in your JSON response.

What is BOM?

You can find that on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

How to check if you have BOM in your response?

1. Open developer tools in chrome and go to network.
2. Find your response file(something like file.php if you dont have htaccess rewrite) and click on it.
3. There are 5 tabs one of them is response. There you will see a red dot if BOM marks are there.

What if you find red doot?

encode your files in utf-8 widouth BOM.
In notepad++ you have an option in "encoding" tab.

PS: my english sucks and I know it :P